# Como versionar API REST?

Tags: php, api, rest, silex

É uma boa prática versionar nossas API's? ex: (http://localhost/api/v1/resources)
Se sim, qual melhor prática para versionar? Estou usando servidor Apache com micro framework Silex PHP, eu poderia criar uma pasta/diretório dentro do app com nome de "v1" ou isso deveria ser tratado nas rotas?
Qual melhor abordagem?

Comment: Você **precisa** versionar? As versões são incompatíveis?

Comment: ainda não, mas e se precisar modificar algo no futuro?

Comment: Dei uma lida no api standards da Casa Branca, mas não entendi como é feito versionamento. https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards

Comment: Aí eles exigem sempre versionar na URL, como no seu exemplo. Faz sentido se vc pensar que são dados/sistemas de governo e tal. Tem que saber o seu caso. Faz sentido versionar se você for lançar mudanças incompatíveis - se a sua API tiver vida longa o suficiente pra isso, inclusive - ou se for muito complicado atualizar os sitemas que vão consumir a sua API. Tudo depende.